# PowerShell: add new route based on dynamic Interface index

Tags: powershell

I have a daily procedure of running route print to find Interface Index for new VPN connection
and then doing `ROUTE ADD {IP} MASK {MASK} IF {InterfaceIndex}`.

I think it could be better a single script in PowerShell.

There in PS I can run:
`Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias "{InterfaceAlias}"`
that returns ifIndex.

Then I am not sure. 
Is it `New-NetRoute` I need to run? And how do I feed IfIndex there with IP and MASK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do the following to add a non-persistent route:

```
$InterfaceAlias = '{InterfaceAlias}'
$Params = @{
    InterfaceAlias = $InterfaceAlias
    NextHop = (Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceAlias $InterfaceAlias).IPv4DefaultGateway.NextHop
    AddressFamily = 'IPv4'
    DestinationPrefix = '{IP}/{NetworkBits}' # Example: 192.168.100.0/24
    PolicyStore = 'ActiveStore'
}
$null = New-NetRoute @Params
Get-NetRoute @Params
```

**Explanation:**

- [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) is used here (`@Params`) simply to make the `*-NetRoute` commands more readable.
- You only need to update `$InterfaceAlias` with your interface name and update `DestinationPrefix` using CIDR notation.
- `$null =` is used to suppress the output of `New-NetRoute` and can be removed if you want to see the output.
- If you want the route to persist across reboots, then remove the `PolicyStore = 'ActiveStore'` line. By default, the `New-NetRoute` command adds the route to the Active Store (not persistent) and the Persistent Store.
- Accessing the `.IPv4DefaultGateway` of the `Get-NetIPConfiguration $InterfaceAlias` command, returns the `NextHop` property needed for `New-NetRoute`.
- Interface aliases can be shared across multiple indexes. You see this when you have IPv4 and IPv6 enabled. A difference between an IPv4 and IPv6 common interface alias is the interface index. Since we are specifically targeting the IPv4 family of addresses in our commands, we don't need to specify or query for the index.

**Note:** The `New-NetRoute` command must be run as admin.

Additional Considerations:

---

In case you are not comfortable with CIDR notation, you can use the following, which will allow using the network mask.

```
$InterfaceAlias = '{InterfaceAlias}'
$DestinationNetwork = '{DestinationIP}' # 192.168.200.0 for example
$Mask = '{MASK}' # 255.255.255.0 for example

$CIDR = "{0}/{1}" -f $DestinationNetwork,(-join ($Mask -split '\.' |% {[convert]::ToString($_,2).Trim('0')})).Length
$Params = @{
    InterfaceAlias = $InterfaceAlias
    NextHop = (Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceAlias $InterfaceAlias).IPv4DefaultGateway.NextHop
    AddressFamily = 'IPv4'
    DestinationPrefix = $CIDR
    PolicyStore = 'ActiveStore'
}
$null = New-NetRoute @Params
Get-NetRoute @Params
```

**Explanation:** Here just update `$InterfaceAlias`, `$DestinationNetwork`, and `$Mask` for your situation.

Comment: Thank you. And where do I specify MASK like I did with batch before?

Comment: You do not need to do that. You can use CIDR notation, i.e. mask 255.255.255.0 is /24. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, need to pick up with that CIDR... Googled that based on CIDR Subnet Table I need two /16 and /24 as I was doing two route adds before.

Comment: I can add a piece of code to convert it for you if you like.

Comment: @RandyMcKay, I added another code block that will accept Mask and do the conversion for you.

Comment: No, I think I have IP/bits part correct. 
I am not sure why -InterfaceIndex is not feeded? Does NextHop substitute it?

Comment: If you have IPv4 and IPv6 enabled, you can have two interfaces that share the same interface alias, but they will differ by the index. Since I'm using AddressFamily IPv4, you return only a single interface now. NextHop is the default gateway (the IPv4 address) of that interface. You can change that if you don't like it.

Comment: I think to do it like this.
$InterfaceAlias = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
$IfIndex = (Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceAlias $InterfaceAlias).InterfaceIndex
New-NetRoute -InterfaceIndex $IfIndex -DestinationPrefix 'IP/16' -PolicyStore 'ActiveStore' -AddressFamily 'IPv4' 
New-NetRoute -InterfaceIndex $IfIndex -DestinationPrefix 'IP/24' -PolicyStore 'ActiveStore' -AddressFamily 'IPv4' 

but it does not work saying route already exists. Should I still look into NextHop direction?

Comment: If you already added it, you will have to remove it to add it back. Why are you not adding the next hop?

Comment: yes, but how do add it with two IPs/Bits in single line?

Comment: If you don't add `-nexthop`, it will default to '0.0.0.0'. You will have to check your routes to see if that already exists.

Comment: If you mean you want to add two destination IPs at the same time, it does not support that. You will have to run either two commands or loop through them. Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: nexthop from the example in the answer doesn't work for me in PS ISE either giving:
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'NextHop'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.

Comment: I initially had two commands: ROUTE ADD xx.x.x.x MASK xxxxxx IF 56
ROUTE ADD xxxx MASK xxxxx IF 56
IF is what I was picking from route print

Comment: so your VPN connect does not provide a gateway. that's why that is null. you will have to remove it. do you always know what the gateway is for the VPN connection? Do you want the nexthop to just be the IP address assigned by the VPN connection?

Comment: yes but the assignment was historically 0: ROUTE ADD xx.x.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 0.0.0.0 IF 46
ROUTE ADD xxx.xxx.xx.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0 IF 46

Comment: my reputation is too low for quick chat :L

Comment: so `New-NetRoute -interfaceindex 46 -DestinationPrefix 'x.x.0.0/16'` and `New-NetRoute -interfaceindex 46 -DestinationPrefix 'x.x.x.0/24'` work, yes?

Comment: for the one that gives you the error, does `Get-NetRoute -interfaceindex 46 -DestinationPrefix 'x.x.x.x/xx'` return a result?

Comment: You can still run `Route Add` in PowerShell. Just run use the variable for the index in the PowerShell script.